# In C#, what's the best way to deal with partially received messages using SocketAsyncEventArgs Buffer

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, buffer

In order to clean some messy code and get a better understanding of the SocketAsyncEventArgs class, I'd to know what's the most efficient technique to reassemble partially received messages from SocketAsyncEventArgs buffers.

To give you the big picture, I'm connected to a TCP server using a C# Socket client that will essentially receive data. The data received is message-based delimited by a \n character.

As you're probably already aware of, when using the ReceiveAsync method, this is almost a certitude that the last received message will be uncompleted such as you'll have to locate the index of the last complete message, copy the incomplete buffer section and keep it as start for the next received buffer and so on.

The thing is, I wish to abstract this operation from the upper layer and call the ProcessReceiveDataImpl as soon I get completed messages in the _tmpBuffer. I found that my Buffer.BlockCopy is not much readable (very old code also (-:) but anyway I wish to know what are you doing in this typical use case?

Code to reassemble messages:

```
public class SocketClient
{
    private const int _receiveBufferSize = 8192;
    private byte[] _remBuffer = new byte[2 * _receiveBufferSize];
    private byte[] _tmpBuffer = new byte[2 * _receiveBufferSize];

    private int _remBufferSize = 0;
    private int _tmpBufferSize = 0;

    private void ProcessReceiveData(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        // the buffer to process
        byte[] curBuffer = e.Buffer;
        int curBufferSize = e.BytesTransferred;
        int curBufferOffset = e.Offset;
        int curBufferLastIndex = e.BytesTransferred - 1;
        int curBufferLastSplitIndex = int.MinValue;

        if (_remBufferSize > 0)
        {
            curBufferLastSplitIndex = GetLastSplitIndex(curBuffer, curBufferOffset, curBufferSize);

            if (curBufferLastSplitIndex != curBufferLastIndex)
            {
                // copy the remain + part of the current into tmp
                Buffer.BlockCopy(_remBuffer, 0, _tmpBuffer, 0, _remBufferSize);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(curBuffer, curBufferOffset, _tmpBuffer, _remBufferSize, curBufferLastSplitIndex + 1);
                _tmpBufferSize = _remBufferSize + curBufferLastSplitIndex + 1;

                ProcessReceiveDataImpl(_tmpBuffer, _tmpBufferSize);

                Buffer.BlockCopy(curBuffer, curBufferLastSplitIndex + 1, _remBuffer, 0, curBufferLastIndex - curBufferLastSplitIndex);
                _remBufferSize = curBufferLastIndex - curBufferLastSplitIndex;
            }
            else
            {
                // copy the remain +  entire current into tmp
                Buffer.BlockCopy(_remBuffer, 0, _tmpBuffer, 0, _remBufferSize);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(curBuffer, curBufferOffset, _tmpBuffer, _remBufferSize, curBufferSize);

                ProcessReceiveDataImpl(_tmpBuffer, _remBufferSize + curBufferSize);
                _remBufferSize = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            curBufferLastSplitIndex = GetLastSplitIndex(curBuffer, curBufferOffset, curBufferSize);

            if (curBufferLastSplitIndex != curBufferLastIndex)
            {
                // we must copy the unused byte into remaining buffer
                _remBufferSize = curBufferLastIndex - curBufferLastSplitIndex;
                Buffer.BlockCopy(curBuffer, curBufferLastSplitIndex + 1, _remBuffer, 0, _remBufferSize);

                // process the msg 
                ProcessReceiveDataImpl(curBuffer, curBufferLastSplitIndex + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                // we can process the entire msg
                ProcessReceiveDataImpl(curBuffer, curBufferSize);
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void ProcessReceiveDataImpl(byte[] buffer, int bufferSize)
    {

    }

    private int GetLastSplitIndex(byte[] buffer, int offset, int bufferSize)
    {
        for (int i = offset + bufferSize - 1; i >= offset; i--)
        {
            if (buffer[i] == '\n')
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Your input is very important and appreciated!
Thank you!

**Updated:**
Also, rather then calling the ProcessReceiveDataImpl and block further receive operations, will it be useful to queue completed messages and make them available to the consumer?